# `SchemaResolver` not being called when a custom one is implemented

Tags: rust, jsonschema

I want a custom `SchemaResolver` to modify the `$id`, which is the absolute path for the `$ref` in json schemas. So I need a new resolver that replaces `$id` with the root of my generic schemas folder. But I implemented this script, but the `resolve` function is not called at all. Could you please help me understand whether I've made a mistake in using this trait or if it's possible that the resolve method is not implemented in the library?

```
impl SchemaResolver for CustomResolver {
   fn resolve(
        &self,
        root_schema: &Value,
        url: &Url,
        original_reference: &str
    ) -> Result<Arc<Value>,SchemaResolverError>{
       let mut schema = root_schema.clone();
       log::info!("url: {:?}", url);
       log::info!("nobody calls me?");
       println!("original_reference: {:?}", original_reference);
       schema["$id"] = "file:///Users/maryam/projects/play-rust/json_schema/schemas".to_string().into();
       Ok(Arc::new(schema))
    }
}

fn main() {
    load_schema().unwrap();
}

fn load_schema() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let json = fs::read_to_string("schemas/schema.json")?;
    let schema = serde_json::from_str(&json)?;

    let compiled_schema = JSONSchema::options()
                .with_draft(Draft::Draft202012)
                .with_resolver(CustomResolver{})
                .compile(&schema);

    println!("{:?}", compiled_schema);
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a struct and to instantiate your custom resolver.

```
struct CustomResolver { <------ THIS
    param: Str,
}


impl SchemaResolver for CustomResolver {
   fn resolve(
        &self,
        root_schema: &Value,
        url: &Url,
        original_reference: &str
    ) -> Result<Arc<Value>,SchemaResolverError>{
       let mut schema = root_schema.clone();
       log::info!("url: {:?}", url);
       log::info!("nobody calls me?");
       println!("original_reference: {:?}", original_reference);
       schema["$id"] = "file:///Users/maryam/projects/play-rust/json_schema/schemas".to_string().into();
       Ok(Arc::new(schema))
    }
}

fn main() {
    load_schema().unwrap();
}

fn load_schema() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let json = fs::read_to_string("schemas/schema.json")?;
    let schema = serde_json::from_str(&json)?;
    let customresolver = CustomResolver::new("param"); <------ THIS
    let compiled_schema = JSONSchema::options()
                .with_draft(Draft::Draft202012)
                .with_resolver(customresolver)
                .compile(&schema);

    println!("{:?}", compiled_schema);
    Ok(())
}
```